# java login & signup form issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm learning Java in school right now and I've tried to make a little login/signup form. So everyone who wants to play my small game has to signup/login first to get their stats loaded. I've seen some basic login forms when I searched some solutions on google, but always with lines like this:
    `if ( username_tf.getText() == "admin" && password_tf.getText() == "123" ) { ...`
But I want people to be able to make their own username & password. That's what I was trying to do:

```
int i;
String username[] = new String[500];
String password[] = new String[500];

// REGISTER BUTTON - no if else yet, just the basics I need to test login button
public void jButton2_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  username[i] = jTextField1.getText();
  password[i] = jPasswordField1.getText();
  i++;
} // end of jButton2_ActionPerformed

// LOGIN BUTTON
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
      username[j] = jTextField1.getText();     // same error without this line
      password[j] = jPasswordField1.getText(); // "
      if ( username[j].equals(username[i]) && password[j].equals(password[i]) ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, username[j] + ", welcome back.", "Successfully logged in.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      } else {
        if ( !username[j].equals(username[i]) ) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong username.", "Error.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else if ( !password[j].equals(password[i]) ) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong password.", "Error.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else if ( !username[j].equals(username[i]) && !password[j].equals(password[i]) ) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong username & password.", "Mega Error.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
      } // end of if-else
    } // end of for
  } // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed
```

I've tried the same code with == operators, but I'm still getting the same error. ^^
I'm getting the Username is wrong option pane always, can somebody help me there? :)
Would appreciate any kind of help and therefore I'm new to Java I'd also appreciate if you could explain why you're using it when you use some difficult code. :D

Comment: where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: It's not an error in the editor, it's always this line I'm getting as output when I try to login after I've signed up     ` if ( !username[j].equals(username[i]) ) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong username.", "Error.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }`

Comment: what is `i` and `j`?

Comment: i should be the counter like when I click on the signup button i increases by 1 so the programm knows ok username[1] is john, when I click it again then username[2] is max for example. j is the counter that compares all the [i] arrays with the text inside the textfields. if username & password are the same then one of the saved [i] arrays, then I'll get logged in. if the j array does not equal the i array, then I'm getting wrong username/password. thats how I wanted to do it. :)